# How to reset a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view which is called on from the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT [Position], [TeamName], [Played], [Wins], [Loss], [Draws], [Points], [Goals_Scored], [Goals_Against], [Goal_Difference], [LeagueID]  
FROM League_Table
WHERE LeagueID = @LeagueID
ORDER BY Points DESC, Goal_Difference DESC;
```

This outputs a league table shown below.

[image]

I have an if statement that checks for if the total matches per team is reached (this means the season is finished), then (this is part I'm stuck on), Simply refresh the table so everything starts again.

```
IF (SELECT MIN(Played) FROM dbo.League_Table WHERE LeagueID = @LeagueID) > @TotalMatches
```

My question is what is the best method to reset a league table? Below is an example of what it should look like after refresh:

[image]

Comment: UPDATE TableName SET Played = 0, Wins = 0, Loss = 0 etc

Comment: Table has big data?

Comment: You actually want to remove all the historical data and just be left with a list of teams? Or do you want a new LeagueID with all the same teams?

Comment: @Paul well actually i will need a new season ID to acknowledge it's a new season. I already have a 'Season' table to determine this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this table have large sets of data, I think an insert to a new table and reinsert to this will perform faster:

```
sp_rename dbo.League_Table, dbo.League_Table_old; -- rename old table

CREATE TABLE dbo.League_Table AS (.....); -- create same table

INSERT INTO dbo.League_Table
SELECT t.leagueID,t.teamName,0,0,0,0,0,null,null,null
FROM dbo.League_Table_old t --insert values to new table
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sagi. One small question, how do you set an increment at the end of the old table name so that for every old league table, it contains a number at the end to keep the names unique?

Comment: No sure I'm following.. Please rephrase the question

Comment: You said rename the league table to dbo.League_Table_old, which is fine, but if I complete another season, I will have another dbo.League_Table_old. Is there a way to make it dbo.League_Table_old1 and dbo.League_Table_old2?

Comment: Why not just manually? You can also use 1 old table, and store `ID_LEAGUE` as uniqueness for each league . (And then insert to the table every time instead of recreating for each season)

Comment: So if I use 1 old table, I can store a 'SeasonID' as a uniqueness for each LeagueID? I may need help on coding that insert for a uniqueness based on season